# Qt create and write 16 bit png images

Tags: image, qt

is it possible to create and write a 16 bit greyscale png image using QT? I have an array of integers and want to write it to a 16 bit buffer, create a qimage and write it. I saw there is something called as depth to set number of bits, but could not find syntax to create an image of 16 bits. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#depth

Comment: Are you sure you really need to many bits for one color plane only? I see png supports 16 bits greyscale, so you might have luck with the libpng directly.

Comment: yes, i need 16 bits for images, we need a high range in the intensity values, i will have a look at libpng, thanks for pointing at it, but is it possible to do it in qt?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know. Anyway, libpng seems to be portable. You might have a look if possible to extend QImage on your own.